# AngularJs - modules must be fully configured before other modules can import them?

Tags: angularjs, module

I am working on a large application, with lots of modules depending on other modules. My issue is that I may get a situation where a module imports another module, before the imported module is fully configured.

For example:

```
// --------------------------------------
// create-directives-module.js

// Create 'guthub.directives' module
angular.module('guthub.directives', []);

// --------------------------------------
// create-main-module.js

// Import 'guthub.directives' module right away into module 'guthub'
angular.module('guthub', ['guthub.directives']);

// --------------------------------------
// create-focus-directive.js

// After 'guthub.directives' has been imported into 'guthub', 
// add a directive 'focus' to 'guthub.directives'
angular.module('guthub.directives').directive('focus',
    function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    element[0].focus();
            }
};
});
```

Would the 'focus' directive be available in the 'guthub' module, even though it has been configured into 'guthub.directives' after 'guthub.directives' was imported into 'guthub'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining modules with dependencies, those dependencies aren't loaded on the spot - you are simply declaring them for injection later. Also, Angular doesn't bootstrap until it matches an `ng-app` attribute in your document after following the dom ready event. So the your code should work just fine.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UvcDd5vgCPaM4wG61SA3?p=preview)